# rails PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

am trying to show pictures from database where they been uploaded withing the same week and have like. here is how i do it

```
def trending_wide
  # binding.pry
  date = DateTime.now.utc
  likes = Like.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', date.beginning_of_week, date.utc.end_of_week).select(:selfy_id)
  time = 'created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', date.beginning_of_week, date.utc.end_of_week
  top = Selfy.where(id: likes, created_at: time)
  top.order("COALESCE(likes_count, 0) DESC").limit(6)
end
```

and am getting this error

```
PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?"
LINE 1: ...23:59:59.999999')) AND "selfies"."created_at" IN ('created_a...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "selfies" WHERE "selfies"."id" IN (SELECT "likes"."selfy_id" FROM "likes" WHERE (created_at >= '2017-02-20 00:00:00' and created_at <= '2017-02-26 23:59:59.999999')) AND "selfies"."created_at" IN ('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', '2017-02-20 00:00:00', '2017-02-26 23:59:59.999999') LIMIT $1) subquery_for_count
```

what am i doing wrong here

Comment: Isn't it 'created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?

Comment: can you give example

Comment: `"created_at" IN ('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', '2017-02-20 00:00:00', '2017-02-26 23:59:59.999999')` is very suspicious in the generated SQL.

Comment: Sorry mate, I am not so keen on SQL queries, but I thought the AND must be capitalized for queries. You might try. May be it works also with 'and' ... => I mean the 'and' in the line that I copied above in the comment...Hä?!

Comment: try `Like.where(created_at: Time.current.all_week)` more readable I think,  http://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Calculations/all_week

Comment: base on your answer, am able to solve it. look at the answer below

Answer (score 0):

based on the answers giving above, am able to solve it with this

```
 def trending_wide
  # binding.pry
  date = DateTime.now.utc
  likes = Like.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', date.beginning_of_week, date.utc.end_of_week).select(:selfy_id)
  top = Selfy.where(id: likes, created_at: Time.current.all_week)
  top.order("COALESCE(likes_count, 0) DESC").limit(6)
end
```

Comment: and remember this `a = "foo", "bar", Date.today` the output will be an array, like `time`.